# How can I shutdown multiple systems using terminal?

Tags: 14.04, command-line

How can I shutdown multiple systems using the terminal?

Also, is it possible to send a message to multiple computers before shutting them down?

I cannot login to them via SSH, but all the computers are connected to same Wi-Fi network.

Is there any other way around?

Comment: What are these "multiple systems"? Can you `ssh` into them?

Comment: No, i cannot. Is there any other way around? All the computers are connected to same Wi-Fi network. @waltinator

Comment: In general, computers are not configured to accept shutdown commands from external sources, but only from privileged local (running on the same machine) sources. Why do you want to do this? Practical joke? Evil hack?

Comment: To prank  them : P    But, you can do that in windows , right? In  my high school, they replaced windows with ubuntu.  I just wanted to know if we can do that in ubuntu too. @waltinator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I shutdown multiple systems using the terminal?

You connect to the system and issue a "shutdown". Easiest method is using "ssh". A script like this ...

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -t {user}@{ip-adres-1} "echo {pwd} | sudo -S poweroff"
ssh -t {user}@{i-padres-2} "echo {pwd} | sudo -S poweroff"
```

There is software to do this (and more) called "[puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/)", "[chef](https://www.chef.io/)" or "[cfengine](https://cfengine.com/)". Even "webmin" can do it (but I doubt any admin would install that and let anyone shutdown a machine from it).

> Also, is it possible to send a message to multiple computers before shutting them down?

Sure. The command "talk" can be used for that.

```
talk user@hostname
```

---

Both (usage of "ssh" and "talk" require installation of software and permission to use. Only software to communicate on the same machine will be installed by default.

---

> I cannot login to them via SSH

Then please explain how you are supposed to get access to those machines?

> To prank them : P

We take security seriously. Letting random people at random times shutdown machines will destroy unsaved data. It could kill something important. Or even crucial.

> But, you can do that in windows , right?

No, same rule applies with Windows: -only- if the administrator lets you.